# How do I prove that this Diophantine equation has no solutions?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, diophantine-equations

How can I prove that

$$x^4 - 4y^4 = 2z^2$$

has no solution for positive integers?

Thanks.

Comment: My failed attempt at modbashing: If $x$ is odd, then the equation fails modulo $2$. Thus $x$ must be even. But then $2^4$ divides the LHS, so $2^4$ must divide the RHS. In particular, $2^3$ must divide $z^2$, so $2^4$ must divide $z^2$. But this means $2^5$ divides the RHS, so $2^5$ must divide the LHS. Now I'm stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the power of two dividing each of the terms.

- If $2^m$ is the highest power of two dividing $x^4$ then $m$ is necessarily a multiple of four.
- If $2^n$ is the highest power of two dividing $4y^4$ then $n$ is congruent to two modulo four.
- If $2^k$ is the hightest power of two dividing $2z^2$ then $k$ is odd.

Hence all those powers of two are distinct. So if we divide the equation by the lowest of them, in the resulting equation there is a single odd term. Contradiction.

---

So just a $2$-adic argument.

Comment: Thanks a lot I did't know that method, I was struggling with that trying to find a solution which converts the equation into a fermat equation, I liked this approach, thanks a lot

Comment: Thanks, @Javier. If you ever have a chance to learn about $p$-adic numbers, then this kind of an argument comes naturally. The idea is used repeatedly there.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: We show that $|a^4-4b^4|=2c^2$ has no non-zero solutions. The proof is by descent. Suppose there is a solution. Then $a$ and $c$ must be even, say $a=2d$ and $c=2e$. Expand and cancel. We get $|4d^4-b^4|=2e^2$.

**Remark:** One can alternately rephrase the solution by using the Least Number Principle (well-ordering of the positive integers, aka induction). If there is a non-zero solution of $|a^4-4b^4|=2c^2$, there is a solution with $a^4+4b^4+2c^2$ minimal. But $4d^4+b^4+2e^2\lt a^4+4b^4+2c^2$.

Comment: What is a proof by descent? I don't know the term. EDIT: When you write $a=2c$, is that a typo?

Comment: Infinite descent, a term invented by Fermat.  For people who don't know the term, I will add a remark.

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee: Thanks, yes it was a typo, the numbers are now called $d$ and $e$, since $c$ was already taken.

Comment: Ok I read the new version and I agree, thanks for the solution

Comment: $a$  is even because $a^4$ is even. So $a^4$ is divisible by $4$, indeed by $16$. It follows that $a^4-4b^4$ is divisible by $4$. So $2c^2$ is divisible by $4$, and therefore $c$ is even.

Comment: Yes I edited my answer because I understood other thing at the beginning, it's really nice answer, and it helps me a lot, Thanks André

Comment: You are welcome. I did it this way because it feels Fermat-like, an he used descent.

Answer (score 0):

You can relate this to an EC by dividing both of side with y^4. Then we have 
$2Y^2=X^4-4$ where $X=x/y$ and $Y=z/y^2$. Now you can discuss on the solutions of this curve.